# Elegantly exposing properties in Unity inspector

Tags: unity, c#

There are various game objects in my scene that share some common characteristics, so I created an interface, like so:

```
public interface IHasLimitedRangeOfMotionAlongZAxis
{
    float MinimumZ { get; } 
    float MaximumZ { get; } 
}
```

For certain types that implement this interface, I would like `MinimumZ` and `MaximumZ` to be publicly assignable in the Unity inspector. Therefore, I would like to be able to expose these properties in Unity.

I am aware that one approach is to write C# scripts in the `Editor` folder to implement an `ExposePropertyAttribute` (see [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Expose_properties_in_inspector)).

However, this approach is unsatisfactory for two reasons:

1. My solution is not co-located with my `Assets` folder. I write my code in a separate solution, and then use `pdb2mdb.exe` to import my scripts into my Unity scenes. (The reason for doing this is to avail myself of C# language features introduced beyond C# 4.0, which nonetheless target .NET Framework 3.5.)
2. I shall have to create a custom editor for every single type that implements the interface with publicly assignable properties. This leads to a lot of boilerplate code.

Is there a more elegant approach than adding private backing fields with the `SerializeField` attribute for all of my public properties?

Comment: It should be noted for newer readers that current versions of Unity support later C# features natively, so the workaround described above with pdb2mdb.exe should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Auto-Implemented Property Field-Targeted Attributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.3/auto-prop-field-attrs) to expose properties in the inspector. You still have to use `SerializeField` but you don't need to write the backing field manually anymore.

```
[field: SerializeField]
public Transform Ball { get; set; }
```

---

This is only supported in newer versions of Unity that support C# 7.3.

*Clarification:* By newer versions of Unity, I mean any version of Unity that supported the .NET 4.6 runtime (I think). The documentation does not exist for all versions, but it has been supported since at least Unity 2018.4 *[[source](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html)]*.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK at the moment there aren't solutions different from using `[SerializeField]` on the private fields of the property or implementing some editor code that exposes properties like the one you linked.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like `MinimumZ` and `MaximumZ` to be publicly assignable in the Unity inspector.

This is not possible. You've declared these properties as read only.

> ```
> float MinimumZ { get; } //no setter
> float MaximumZ { get; }
> ```

No matter what inspector options exist or are possible, or even might be possible for Interface types, you've explicitly denied writing to these properties.

The only option you have is using `[SerializeField]` on the private backing object.

Comment: I can have a class that implements ``IHasLimitedRangeOfMotionAlongZAxis`` with ``public float MinimumZ { get; set; }``, and also inherits from ``MonoBehaviour``. If I assign the script containing this class to a game object, I would like ``MinimumZ`` to show up in the inspector. Is this not possible?

Comment: @MY_G I think at that point you fall under the purview of [Galandil's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/155488/75627). In either case I haven't tried, but I saw your Interface definition and knew there was going to be a problem regardless of what might exist.

Comment: Autoproperties are the bane of Unity's Inspector. :D